# Error: Framework 'Mono / .NET 3.5' not installed

Tags: unity

Recently I installed Ubuntu-Mate 16.10. Unity and Monodevelop works, but when I try to compile the javascript on Monodevelop, appears an error:

Error: Framework 'Mono / .NET 3.5' not installed. (Assembly-CSharp)

On 14.04 all works very well but not here....what is the way to fix this problem??

I searched on the internet and I can't find the answer.

Comment: Not sure, this may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185770/older-version-of-net-not-installed-with-latest-mono in the accepted answer there is a blogpost on how to install 3.5.

Comment: I tried this, not worked...now, I'm working without using compiler on Mono, only saving the script, but I like to see the errors on the program, is more confortable.

Answer (score 2):

**Change your target Framework in MonoDevelop**

- In the solution explorer, go to **Assembly-CSharp** and click on the little cogwheel.
  [image: Assembly-CSharp]
- In the Dropdown, select **Options**
- Then, under **Build / General** select whatever is installed on you machine.

---

Alternatively, if you want to stick with 3.5, you can install the Mono reference assemblies like this:

`sudo apt install mono-reference-assemblies-3.5`